# How to add a word to the end of each string in a specific column (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add "NSW" to the end of each town name in a pandas data frame.The dataframe currently looks like this:

```
0  Parkes         NaN
1  Forbes         NaN
2   Yanco         NaN
3  Orange         NaN
4  Narara         NaN
5   Wyong         NaN
```

I need every town to also have the word NSW added to it

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'] + 'NSW'
```

Comment: Hey, this adds "NSW" to the beginning of the string not the end :/ For examples "NSWParkes"

Comment: @Dhar_ is this is what you need , would you like consider accept and upvote ?

Comment: How would I do this so it only changes the string if NSW is not already there?

Comment: Check with `s=df['Name'].str.contains('NSW');
df['Name']=np.where(s, df['Name'], df['Name']+'NSW')`

Comment: @Dhar_ import numpy as np first

Comment: I am getting the error - Name: FullAddress, dtype: object)' is an invalid key

Comment: (FullAddress is the column name you are calling "Name")